# ImportError: cannot import name 'tensorflow' from partially initialized module 'opt_einsum.backends'

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

when I run this code, I got an error. cannot import name 'tensorflow' from partially initialized module 'opt_einsum.backends'

I have no idea how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add https://github.com/dgasmith/opt_einsum/blob/master/opt_einsum/backends/tensorflow.py to site-packages/opt_einsum/backends/

From https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34351

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall `opt_einsum`
and re-install it using `pip` not `conda`